# Data table with fixed table head and scrollable table body using CSS only

Tags: html, css

There are many solutions to this, but I have few constraints to add up to this problem which makes it difficult to achieve.

I was working on this table with fixed header and scrollable body using only CSS (no Javascript/jquery) and flexible column widths (so that the table gets resized on window resize). Also to make this compatible in all possible browsers including IE6.

The closest solution I could find was http://salzerdesign.com/test/fixedTable.html

But this too has a problem with centring the header text which also overflows (because of fixed height) when window is resized.

Is there a solution for this? Please help.